# In Python, how do I easily generate an image file from some source data?

Tags: python, image, data-visualization

I have some data that I would like to visualize. Each byte of the source data roughly corresponds to a pixel value of the image.

What is the easiest way to generate an image file (bitmap?) using Python?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can create images with a list of pixel values using [Pillow](http://python-pillow.github.io/):

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))
img.putdata(my_list)
img.save('image.png')
```

Comment: More useful examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062920/how-do-i-create-an-image-in-pil-using-a-list-of-rgb-tuples

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) and [pyGame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html).  Both of them allow you to draw on a canvas and then save it to a file.

Comment: Further information about generation of images using Pygame [can be found here](https://www.google.com/search?q=pygame+generate+image&oq=pygame+generate+image&aqs=chrome..69i57.2663j0j8&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).