# Writing pixel information to a file and reading it

Tags: python, list

Can anyone please help me as I'm going round in circles with a problem that should be sooo easy!
I have an array of pixel info which I want to use to recreate a small image. Getting the pixel data is sorted, and this info exists in a 2d array list like this:

```
[(255,0,0),(125,111,2),(.... etc
```

I want to then be able to write this info to a file and read it back in from another program so it is in the same (or similar) format. For example, the colour data for the tenth pixel can be read by pixel[9][0] for the red, pixel[9][1] for green etc.

It seems to me that I should be able to write a list of bytes as all numbers are below 256, then they could each be read back in one at a time and appended to another list. There doesn't seem to be any way to do this! Everything I have tried saves the numbers as individual digits so (255,0,0) is stored as '2','5','5','0','0'. If I try to store numbers, again it just stores digits, and if I try to store bytes, it just brings up errors insisting it can't store ints as bytes. Storing as strings doesn't help either as again the digits are stored together with newlines and stuff I just don't need.

I have had to delete the examples of codes I have tried because no matter what I do, I cannot submit the question as it apparently contains code that is not properly formatted. The only way I can post this is to remove all code!! But i have used the 'write' with int, chr but nothing works for me.

The file will be used for reading on a Raspberry Pi Pico.

Anyone any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Please post the code of what you have tried. To format it just select the code and press ctrl+k  or put the code in between backticks ( ` ` ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```py
# Example pixel data
pixels = [
    (255, 0, 0),    # Red
    (125, 111, 2),  # Some other color
    # Add more pixel data here
]

# Open a file in binary write mode
with open("image_data.bin", "wb") as file:
    for pixel in pixels:
        # Write each color component as a byte
        for color_component in pixel:
            file.write(bytes([color_component]))

# Reading back the data
read_pixels = []
with open("image_data.bin", "rb") as file:
    while True:
        # Read 3 bytes (one for each color component) at a time
        color_components = file.read(3)
        if not color_components:
            break
        # Unpack the bytes into a tuple representing the color
        color = tuple(color_components)
        read_pixels.append(color)

print(read_pixels[0][0]) # The first index represents the pixel, the second index represents the color from that pixel.
```

Comment: Ah, that is very similar to what I was attempting, but I was unaware of how to write bytes (rather than strings or ints). Thank you for that! However, having modified your code to fit my requirements, it bombs out with a memory error :
MemoryError: memory allocation failed, allocating 184 byte
PROBLEM IN THONNY'S BACK-END: Exception while handling 'Run' (thonny.plugins.micropython.mp_back.ManagementError: Command output was not empty).

Comment: Having played about with your code and got nowhere because of memory errors, I had the idea of writing to the LED matrix pixel by pixel as the data is read, rather than store the whole image data in a list, which I guess is why the memory error. And...it worked perfectly first time. The key points that you helped my with were: writing bytes to a file (I wasn't aware of the bytes function, just than the "b" parameter) and reading the bytes back into integers (also not aware of tuple(...) to d othis). So, many thanks for helping me loads!

Answer (score 3):

Lists of pixels are not a natural way to deal with images, since images are 2-d, I mean they have a height and a width and the rows and columns of pixels are naturally indexed like this:

```
image[0,34]
```

The Python structure that most image processing packages use for images is the Numpy `ndarray`. That would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np

# Create empty image 2 rows, 4 columns, and 3 RGB pixels at each location
image = np.zeros((2,4,3), np.uint8)

# 1st row: Red, Green, Blue, Black
image[0,0] = [255,0,0]
image[0,1] = [0,255,0]
image[0,2] = [0,0,255]
image[0,3] = [0,0,0]

# 2nd row: Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, White
image[1,0] = [0,255,255]
image[1,1] = [255,0,255]
image[1,2] = [255,255,0]
image[1,3] = [255,255,255]

# Save to a file
image.tofile('image.rgb')
```

Then if you use Numpy arrays, you have access to PIL/Pillow, OpenCV and scikit-image on your desktop computer to visualise and resize/convert/crop and manipulate images.

However your chosen format has the problem that it is a list and doesn't allow you to know the height and width of the image, so when you reload it you get a list, but no height and width:

```
reloaded = np.fromfile('image.rgb', dtype=np.uint8)
```

If you print that, you get a list of 24 numbers:

```
print(reloaded)
array([255,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0, 0, 255, 255,   0, 255, 255, 255,   0, 255, 255, 255], dtype=uint8)
```

And if you check its shape you can see it is a 1-dimensional list of 24 numbers, not an image with a height and width:

```
print(reloaded.shape)
(24,)
```

So you would need to *"know"* by other means the shape and then reshape it:

```
reloaded = np.fromfile('image.rgb', dtype=np.uint8).reshape((2,4,3))
```

---

You can then manipulate this image from the command-line on your desktop with **ImageMaick**, e.g. scale it up and convert it to PNG:

```
magick -size 4x2 -depth 8 image.rgb -scale 300x bigger.png
```

[image]

---

I don't think Numpy exists in MicroPython, so you can read this image back on the Pico with the code by @hjuste on the Pico.

---

### However...

I don't think this format is very good because it doesn't have the height and width in the image and no other programs can easily read it, manipulate it or display it. I would suggest you use [PPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PPM_example) format instead -  it is very simple with a short header on the front with the image size.

Also, you can write it in ASCII rather than binary so you can edit it with a text editor. It is somewhat inefficient, but as you said, your images are small.

So, in order to write such a plain (ASCII/uncompressed) PPM file, you can use **OpenCV** as follows to write the image I created at the start of my answer:

```
import cv2 as cv

... create "image" like I did above ...

# Save image as ASCII PPM file
cv.imwrite('result.ppm', image, [cv.IMWRITE_PXM_BINARY,0])
```

Then you can read that on your Pico very simply - roughly like this:

```
with open('result.ppm') as f:
    s = f.read()

# Find anything that looks like numbers
l = re.findall(r'[0-9P]+',s)

# Pick up width and height
w, h = int(l[1]), int(l[2])

# Pick up remaining pixels
pixels = l[4:]
```

---

The benefit of using `PPM` format is that:

- your images remain compatible with other tools (ImageMagick, vips, Photoshop, MS-Paint, IrfanView) for visualisation and modification
- they are easily read on the Pico

You can make a red 24x8 PPM image, for example, very simply with **ImageMagick**:

```
magick -size 24x8 xc:red -compress none -depth 8 red.ppm
```

Or resize a PNG and convert to PPM like this:

```
magick image.png -resize 80x40 -compress none -depth 8 image.ppm
```

Comment: I should have said that the images are ones that I have reduced in size to match an LED Matrix, so I will always know the size of the image, which is why I thought a 1-D list would be ok. The output will just be lighting LEDs on a matrix to recreate the image. I wasn't aware of .ppm format. Looks even more straightforward than Bmp.

Comment: Indeed, I wouldn't recommend BMP to anybody.

Comment: Your Cyan example is off, should be `[0,255,255]` instead of `[0,0,255]`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Oops, corrected. Thank you.

Comment: You corrected the text but not the picture produced from it!

Comment: @MarkRansom D'oh, I'm getting positively senile! Corrected again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use .bmp image file format as it is the standard format to store raw images without compression or data loss.

Python has the a lib called Pillow for working with images (to install with your dependency manager like pip).

Here some links that should help you :

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pillow/index.htm
- [How to create image from a list of pixel values in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46923244/how-to-create-image-from-a-list-of-pixel-values-in-python3)

Comment: Thanks. I can't get PIL (or Pillow) to work on Pico (MicroPython), though it works fine on Thonny on my Windows laptop. So I've used PIL to read the image data but I can't get the data to be read in a manageable way on the pico.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
# read pixel data from 64x32 bmp image and store as 2-d array ie pixel[pixel number][rgb data]
im = Image.open('myimage.bmp')
pixels = list(im.getdata())
print(pixels)
with open("image_data.bin", "wb") as file:
    for pixel in pixels:
        # Write each color component as a byte
        for color_component in pixel:
            file.write(bytes([color_component]))    
# ------------------------------------------------------
# 2nd program run on the pico to display the image
import hub75
DISPLAY_WIDTH,DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 64,64
image_x = 64
image_y = 32
h75 = hub75.Hub75(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, stb_invert=False) # set up matrix
h75.start()

with open("image_data.bin", "rb") as file:
    for y in range(image_y):
        for x in range(image_x):
            # Read 3 bytes (one for each color component) at a time
            color_components = file.read(3)
            if not color_components:
                break
            # Unpack the bytes into a tuple representing the color
            color = tuple(color_components)
            # light the relevant led immediately to save memory
            r,g,b = color[0],color[1],color[2]
            h75.set_pixel(x,y,r,g,b)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).