# python creating an image from RGB tuples

Tags: python, image, drawing, draw

I have a muti lined .txt file with image data like this:

```
(198, 252, 247) (255, 255, 250) (254, 253, 248) (251, 252, 246) (247, 248, 240) ... 
(100, 144, 247) (255, 200, 250) (254, 253, 248) (251, 252, 246) (247, 248, 240) ...
```

How do I read these data into tuples?

```
lst = [((198, 252, 247), (255, 255, 250)), (second line), (thrid) ...]
```

and eventually draw each line back into an image file using the `Image` module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create an image in PIL using a list of RGB tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062920/how-do-i-create-an-image-in-pil-using-a-list-of-rgb-tuples)

Comment: @SoumeshBanerjee no, I'm trying to read the tuples from file

Comment: what is the delimiter for the tuples?

Comment: @SoumeshBanerjee I can change the space to dashes if that makes life easier. so it will be: `(198, 252, 247)-(255, 255, 250)-(254, 253, 248)-...`

Comment: @AK_, you say: *"I'm trying to read the tuples from file"*.Then, just ask how to read tuples from file. Simplify the question.

Comment: @danihp done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply read each line, extract the value triplets from it, and convert them to integers.

```
import re

triplet = r'\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)' # regex pattern

image = []
with open('image.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        image.append([(int(x), int(y), int(z)) for x, y, z in re.findall(triplet, line)])
```

**EDIT**

To actually draw the image, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062920/how-do-i-create-an-image-in-pil-using-a-list-of-rgb-tuples). However, this should work:

```
from PIL import Image

width, height = len(image[0]), len(image)
data = sum(image, []) # ugly hack to flatten the image

im = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))
im.putdata(data)
im.save('image.png')
```

Comment: this worked; but could you please add how to draw the image for each tuple?

Comment: Sure. There you go.

Comment: ok this works; there is a one bug that I will edit and I will mark your reply as answer!

Comment: If ``images = [[(1,1,1),(2,2,2)],[(3,3,3),(4,4,4)]]``, ``sum(image, [])`` flattens it into ``[(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3),(4,4,4)]``, which is what ``putdata`` expects. Your suggested edit of ``map(sum, image)`` just raises a ``TypeError``. :(

Comment: I'm still getting the wrong image size. any idea why?

Comment: Maybe your file is transposed, with rows (i.e. ``len(image)``) being the width and columns (i.e. ``len(image[0])``) being the height?

Comment: can you please document your code? What is exactly the first defintion do?

Comment: It's a regular expression pattern that captures ``(<number>, <number>, <number>)``. See [the ``re`` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to scan and split the data from the file, then you can just parse the tuples from the data (string tuple), then simply create an image object using PIL

```
def getTuple(s):
    try:
        s = eval(str(s))
        if type(s) == tuple:
            return s
        return
    except:
        return

with open("filename.txt", "rb") as fp:
    im_list = []
    data_points = fp.read()
    data_point_list = data_points.split("-")
    for data_point in data_point_list:
        im_list.append(getTuple(data_point))
    # the code snippet from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062920/how-do-i-create-an-image-in-pil-using-a-list-of-rgb-tuples
    im2 = Image.new(im.mode, im.size)
    im2.putdata(list_of_pixels)
```

Comment: getTuple not defined? what am I missing?